# How to open Windows Explorer to a folder using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to write a simple program in Ruby to open a specific folder in Windows.
I'm doing a simple system call to open an explorer window to the path of the folder.  The path I want to open is `\AppData\Roaming\SketchUp\SketchUp 2014`.

When I enter the following:

```
explorer %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\SketchUp\SketchUp 2014
```

my `cmd` window the folder opens no problem. When I put this command inside my ruby script and properly install the program inside sketch up, the folder that opens up is the user's Documents folder. Even if I specify the path of `C:\Users\UserName yada yada yada` it still only opens a folder to the Documents folder. My Mac version of this works perfectly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also make sure to use backslashes (`\`) as your path separator on Windows, otherwise it will not work. And those backslashes should be escaped (i.e., `\\`). So for example, to open your `SketchUp\SketchUp 2014` folder:

```
appdata = ENV['appdata']
path = [appdata, 'SketchUp', 'SketchUp 2014']

pathstr = path.join(File::ALT_SEPARATOR) # File::SEPARATOR == '/', we need "\\"
# => "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\SketchUp\\SketchUp 2014"

# Pass as argument to explorer call:

`explorer #{pathstr}`
# or
system("explorer #{pathstr}")
# or
system('explorer %s' % pathstr)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your syntax André but a window popped up saying that no application is known to open this URL.
To indicate the system that I want to open a path in the Finder (on Mac) and not an URL using my default web browser, I had to modify slightly your code :

```
UI.openURL("file:///#{path)}")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30762503)

Answer (score 0):

Sketchup Api have a code for this job. For works inside sketchup, write the following code:

```
myPlugin_folder = Sketchup.find_support_file("Plugins")
UI.openURL(myPlugin_folder)
```

i hope this helps you.